# How can i create a filter by with Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

My MVC view currently displays the following

[image]

I would like to perform filtering with a linq based on user selection so i can display the filtered results only.

My controller is like

```
var Products = db.Products.AsQueryable();

public class FilterPageViewModel
{
    public int?[] man { get; set; }
    public int?[] size { get; set; }
    public int?[] color { get; set; }
    public decimal? minPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? maxPrice { get; set; }
    public Sorting Sorting {get ; set; }
    public Order Order {get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index(int? CategoryID = 0, 
                          int? page = 0,
                          FilterPageViewModel model = null)
{

    //Manufacturer #############################################
    if (model.man != null) 
    {
        foreach (int? i in model.man) 
        {
            if (i.HasValue) 
            {
                //Do something here
            }
        }
    }

    //Size ######################################################
    if (model.size != null)
    {
        foreach (int? i in model.size)
        {
            if (i.HasValue)
            {
                //Do something here
            }
        }
    }

    //Color ######################################################
    if (model.color != null)
    {
        foreach (int? i in model.color)
        {
            if (i.HasValue)
            {
                //Do something here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess i should perform something like...

```
Where Brand is 'Nike' OR 'Salomon' 
AND Size is 'L' OR 'XL' OR 'XXL'
AND Color is 'Red' OR 'Green' OR 'Blue'
```

Of course the text within '' above are id's and replaced for clarification purposes.

I am sorry if i have not made my self clear but my tongue language is not English.

Comment: Show us how you would get a list of all products to set the foundation.

Comment: Show us some input data you have and some output you expect. In your psuedo linq you do not have a select. The where part of a query just contains the predicate to filter but what is the output? Linq queries have a select statement. Maybe it is an idea to play with these examples. This is how many have have learned linq.https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: @Daan I will check these right now.

Comment: filtering is done in LINQ by calling `enum.Where(Predicate)` where `enum` is some `IEnumerable<T>` and `Predicate` is some `Func<T, bool>`, e.g. `var evenNumbers = numbers.Where(number => number % 2 == 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something along these lines since you have an IQueryable provider for your Linq to SQL.

```
var filteredProducts = Products;
if(model.man != null)
    filteredProducts = filteredProducts.Where(x => (from man in model.man where man.HasValue() select man.Value).Contains(x.manId));
if(model.size != null)
    filteredProducts = filteredProducts.Where(x => (from size in model.size where size.HasValue() select size.Value).Contains(x.sizeId));
//etc
var enumerate = filteredProducts.ToList();
```

Because you're working with an IQueryable, the filters won't be evaluated until you actually enumerate the object with a call like ToList() or plug it into a foreach.